# How to convert in fly ADPCM wav file in PSM wave file in c#

Tags: c#, converters, wav

i have next code to convert ADPCM wav in PCM wave how you can do without intermediate storage file to disk here   **`WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("D:\\pcm16000.wav", upsampler);`**

public static byte[] ADPcmToPcm(string waveFileName, int bitRate = 128)
        {

```
        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(waveFileName))
        using (var converter = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(reader))
        using (var upsampler = new WaveFormatConversionStream(new WaveFormat(16000, converter.WaveFormat.Channels), converter))
        {
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile("D:\\pcm16000.wav", upsampler);


            FileStream fs = new FileStream("d:\\pcm16000.wav", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            byte [] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];
            int bytesToRead = (int)fs.Length;
            int bytesRead = 0;
            while (bytesToRead > 0)
            {
                int n = fs.Read(bytes, bytesRead, bytesToRead);
                if (n == 0) break;
                bytesRead += n;
                bytesToRead -= n;
            }
            bytesToRead = bytes.Length;

            return bytes;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Write to a MemoryStream object instead of a FileStream :)

Comment: upsampler is actually an array of bytes (file) without storing it in a physical file using the file WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile further not recognized as PSM wave file and does not play by the player